# MPI write the variable in nested loops to a single file

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, nested-loops

I am currently trying to find an efficient way to parallelize the following structure. The amount of the file is huge around 50Gb and I wonder how the speed of the calculation can be boosted up via MPI or for this kind of cases, parallelism is not an efficient way because of the communication time or barrier for the cores since I want to write the data with an order. Thanks for helping.

```
for m = 1,120
    for n = 1,120
       for k = 1,120

          for i = 1,100

              f= x[k]*y[n]*z[m]

              for j = 1, 30000

                  data[j]= A[i,j]*f

          fwrite(fp,data)
          free(data)
```

Comment: Since the size of the file is 50Gb and 120x120x120x30000 items are written to the file, it seems that `data[j]` is of type `char`. If `f` is of type `char` too, it means that there are only 256 possible values for the array `data`. What about computing these values and storing them in a 256x30000 array (say datap[256][30000]) ?  Then, just `fwrite(fp,datap[f]);`. This would decrease the computation time by 100 without using parallelization. Notice that the file can be deflated as well, since the same line will appear again and again... Just store `f[120][120][120]` and `datap[256][30000] `!

Answer (score 0):

Why is writing in order a challenge?  Both answers to this question provide a way to do exactly that:

[Writing to files with MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356654/writing-to-files-with-mpi?rq=1)